# Symfony 2 - VichUploader can't handle file

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I have very strange problem with VichUploader.

I have 2 entities where for one of them VichUploader works fine (Download Entity)- it saves file in directory and add record to database table. For second entity (Offer) it doesn't work- it displays `Column 'file_name' cannot be null` error. If I have added nullable parameter to fileName property it added record to database table but with NULL file_name (and it DIDN'T save file in directory).

My config.yml

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

    mappings:
        download_file:
            uri_prefix:         /files/download
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/files/download

        offer_file:
            uri_prefix:         /files/offer
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/files/offer

            inject_on_load:     false
            delete_on_update:   false
            delete_on_remove:   true
```

Download entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * Download
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="izo_download")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\DownloadRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Download
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
     *
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="download_file", fileNameProperty="name")
     *
     * @var File $file
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Download
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return Download
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
     * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the  update. If this
     * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
     * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
     * during Doctrine hydration.
     *
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(File $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        if ($file) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->date = new \DateTime('now');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return File
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }
}
```

Offer entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Offer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="izo_offer")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\OfferRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Offer
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="To pole nie może być puste")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @Assert\Type(type="AppBundle\Entity\Client")
     * @Assert\Valid
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="To pole nie może być puste")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="offers",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $clientBelongsTo;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="To pole nie może być puste")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="supportOffers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="contact_person_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $contactPerson;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="createdOffers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="creator_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $createdBy;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Measurement", mappedBy="createdBy")
     */
    private $createdMeasurements;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Measurement", mappedBy="contactPerson")
     */
    private $supportMeasurements;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="createdAt", type="date")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="note", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $note;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="To pole nie może być puste")
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="comesFrom", type="integer")
     */
    private $comesFrom;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="To pole nie może być puste", groups={"creation"})
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="notify", type="date")
     */
    private $notify;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer")
     */
    private $status = 1;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="whyNotSold", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $whyNotSold;

    /**
     *
     * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
     *
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="offer_file", fileNameProperty="fileName")
     *
     * @var File $file
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="file_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $fileName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     *
     * @var \DateTime $updatedAt
     */
    protected $updatedAt;

    /**
     * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
     * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the  update. If this
     * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
     * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
     * during Doctrine hydration.
     *
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(File $file = null)
    {
        $this->$file = $file;

        if ($file) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return File
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $fileName
     */
    public function setFileName($fileName)
    {
        $this->fileName = $fileName;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFileName()
    {
        return $this->fileName;
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Offer
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     *
     * @return Offer
     */
    public function setCreatedAt()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set note
     *
     * @param string $note
     *
     * @return Offer
     */
    public function setNote($note)
    {
        $this->note = $note;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get note
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNote()
    {
        return $this->note;
    }


    /**
     * Set notify
     *
     * @param \DateTime $notify
     *
     * @return Offer
     */
    public function setNotify($notify)
    {
        $this->notify = $notify;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get notify
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getNotify()
    {
        return $this->notify;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param integer $status
     *
     * @return Offer
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set whyNotSold
     *
     * @param integer $whyNotSold
     *
     * @return Offer
     */
    public function setWhyNotSold($whyNotSold)
    {
        $this->whyNotSold = $whyNotSold;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get whyNotSold
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getWhyNotSold()
    {
        return $this->whyNotSold;
    }

    /**
     * Set contactPerson
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $contactPerson
     *
     * @return Offer
     */
    public function setContactPerson(\AppBundle\Entity\User $contactPerson = null)
    {
        $this->contactPerson = $contactPerson;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get contactPerson
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getContactPerson()
    {
        return $this->contactPerson;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdBy
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $createdBy
     *
     * @return Offer
     */
    public function setCreatedBy(\AppBundle\Entity\User $createdBy = null)
    {
        $this->createdBy = $createdBy;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdBy
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getCreatedBy()
    {
        return $this->createdBy;
    }

    /**
     * Set comesFrom
     *
     * @param integer $comesFrom
     *
     * @return Offer
     */
    public function setComesFrom($comesFrom)
    {
        $this->comesFrom = $comesFrom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get comesFrom
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getComesFrom()
    {
        return $this->comesFrom;
    }


    /**
     * Set clientBelongsTo
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Client $clientBelongsTo
     *
     * @return Offer
     */
    public function setClientBelongsTo(\AppBundle\Entity\Client $clientBelongsTo = null)
    {
        $this->clientBelongsTo = $clientBelongsTo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get clientBelongsTo
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Client
     */
    public function getClientBelongsTo()
    {
        return $this->clientBelongsTo;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->createdMeasurements = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->supportMeasurements = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add createdMeasurement
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Measurement $createdMeasurement
     *
     * @return Offer
     */
    public function addCreatedMeasurement(\AppBundle\Entity\Measurement $createdMeasurement)
    {
        $this->createdMeasurements[] = $createdMeasurement;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove createdMeasurement
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Measurement $createdMeasurement
     */
    public function removeCreatedMeasurement(\AppBundle\Entity\Measurement $createdMeasurement)
    {
        $this->createdMeasurements->removeElement($createdMeasurement);
    }

    /**
     * Get createdMeasurements
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getCreatedMeasurements()
    {
        return $this->createdMeasurements;
    }

    /**
     * Add supportMeasurement
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Measurement $supportMeasurement
     *
     * @return Offer
     */
    public function addSupportMeasurement(\AppBundle\Entity\Measurement $supportMeasurement)
    {
        $this->supportMeasurements[] = $supportMeasurement;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove supportMeasurement
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Measurement $supportMeasurement
     */
    public function removeSupportMeasurement(\AppBundle\Entity\Measurement $supportMeasurement)
    {
        $this->supportMeasurements->removeElement($supportMeasurement);
    }

    /**
     * Get supportMeasurements
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getSupportMeasurements()
    {
        return $this->supportMeasurements;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this could be happening because the UploadableField annotation references the field database name, not the model name (eg: file_name, not fileName), but I test this in a working example and everything went fine. Also VichUploaderBundle listen to Doctrine events, this means that you need to update any other field of the entity to trigger the actual upload of the file, easiest way to "force" the upload its setting a field on the file field setter. Here's an example:

```
public function setFile($file)
{
    $this->file= $file;

    if ($this->file) {
        $this->update_date = new \DateTime();
    }

    return $this;
}
```

This is very effective because you ensure that your file is uploaded and attached when the PrePersist or PreUpdate events are triggered. You could listen to the PreUpload and PostUpload events and check the data been handled (this is easily done whit the **dump** function provided by Symfony, Symfony >= 2.6). Hope this helps you